# problem when running SQL Oracle command with ROWID

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I am trying to execute the following, select in TOAD, however the error is occurring: ORA-00933 SQL command not closed named

```
SELECT ROWID,
       ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC, 
       ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.SITUACAO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAINICIAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAFINAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAPREVISTA
  FROM ECM_WF_PROC AS ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS,
  LATERAL(SELECT ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.SITUACAO AS SITUACAO, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAINICIAL AS DATAINICIAL, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAFINAL AS DATAFINAL, 
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.DATAPREVISTA AS DATAPREVISTA
            FROM ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS AS ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS
           WHERE ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.IDEMPRESA = ECM_WF_PROC.IDEMPRESA AND
                 ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.IDWF_PROC = ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC) AS TD_DADOS_ETAPAS
WHERE ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO = '177920';
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHqW8.png

Could you help me how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ROWID` refers to the address of some row so you should provide the name of the table so that Oracle understands that out of multiple tables in your `FROM` clause which table it should consider for `ROWID`.

Use `ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS.ROWID`

Answer (score 0):

Cause of this particular problem (ORA-00933) is the `as` keyword in the `from` clause. Unlike some other databases, in Oracle it raises an error. For example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept as d
  3  where deptno = 10;
from dept as d
          *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

See how SQL*Plus nicely shows where the error occurred? Your TOAD GUI did the same - painted the `as` blue.

Without `as`:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept d
  3  where deptno = 10;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK

SQL>
```

---

In your case, you'd modify

```
FROM ECM_WF_PROC AS ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS
...
               ) AS TD_DADOS_ETAPAS
```

to

```
FROM ECM_WF_PROC    ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS
...
               )    TD_DADOS_ETAPAS
```

Answer (score 0):

I am curious why you are using a lateral join when a simple inner join seems sufficient:

```
SELECT ECM_WF_PROC.ROWID,
       ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC, 
       ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.SITUACAO, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAINICIAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAFINAL, 
       TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.DATAPREVISTA
FROM ECM_WF_PROC ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS JOIN
     FROM ECM_WF_PROC_ETAPAS TD_DADOS_ETAPAS
     ON TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.IDEMPRESA = ECM_WF_PROC.IDEMPRESA AND
        TD_DADOS_ETAPAS.IDWF_PROC = ECM_WF_PROC.IDWF_PROC
WHERE ECM_WF_PROC.PROCESSO = '177920';
```

As the other two answers point out, both `ROWID` and `AS` are problems.  The lateral join *should* work, but it seems awkward to use it when a simple `INNER JOIN` is sufficient.